# jQuery stop only particular resize event

Tags: jquery, events, resize, handler

I am making a JavaScript which uses a popup image like Fancybox (it does not use it).

This auto-centers the image when resizing. But when I click away the image popup, I need to stop the resize event by `$(window).off('resize')` which works. But it also stops all other resize events which I don't want to stop.

How can I stop only this particular resize event?

Comment: Use namespaced event: https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/  But your issue could be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure .. if you take it as a function. it can be call as input `onclick`

```js
function endResize() {
    $(window).off("resize");
    $("#content").width(originalWidth);
    $("#content").height(originalHeight);
}
```